# Concurrent JUnit testing

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, concurrency, junit

I have a large JUnit test suite, where I'd quite like to run all the tests concurrently for two reasons:

- Exploit multiple cores to run the whole test suite faster
- Hopefully detect some errors due to non-thread-safe global objects

I recognise that this will force me to refactor some code to make it thread-safe, but I consider that to be a good thing :-)

What's the best way to get JUnit to run all the tests concurrently?

Answer (score 29):

Are you fixed to JUnit? **TestNG** provides good multi thread testing out of the box and it's compatible with JUnit tests (you need to make a few changes). For example you could run a test like this:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 9,  timeOut = 10000)
public void doSomething() {
...
}
```

This would mean that the `doSomething()` method will be invoked 9 times by 3 different threads.

I highly recommend **TestNG**.

Comment: +1 for TestNG, I use it for all my thread safety tests. It also has nice paramaterized tests.

Comment: Downvoted due to not actually answering the OPs question.  He specifically states he wants to run his entire suite across threads and run a single method multiple times

Comment: @TobyHobson This is a terrible way of testing for thread safety. And by definition not a unit tests since it is not deterministic. And TestNG contains numerous bugs. I fixed some of them lately but they do not get pulled (no suggestion does), TestNG is fairly inactive. Rather try Thread Weaver (http://code.google.com/p/thread-weaver/)

Answer (score 24):

I was looking for an answer to exactly this question, and based on the answers here, and what I read elsewhere, it appears as if there isn't currently an easy out-of-the-box way to run existing tests in parallel using JUnit.  Or if there is I didn't find it.  So I wrote a simple JUnit Runner that accomplishes that.  Please feel free to use it; see http://falutin.net/2012/12/30/multithreaded-testing-with-junit/ for a complete explanation and the source code of the MultiThreadedRunner class.  With this class, you can just annotate your existing test class(es) like this:

```
@RunWith(MultiThreadedRunner.class)
```

Comment: Have you an idea on how to implement a concurrent Suite runner, and not only a concurrent test runner ? Could be helpful too :p

Comment: I haven't looked at that, Stéphane.  But making the test runner was so easy, I bet the suite runner wouldn't be hard either.  If you solve the problem, I'll gladly add your code to my post :)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: It lives again!

Answer (score 22):

The following code should achieve your requirements which was taken from the German book [JUnit Profiwissen](http://www.amazon.de/JUnit-Profiwissen-Effizientes-Arbeiten-Standardbibliothek-automatische/dp/3864900204/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412676922&sr=8-1&keywords=JUnit) which contains some hints to either tests stuff in parallel or on how to reduce execution time through using multiple cores instead of only a single core.

JUnit 4.6 introduced a ParallelComputer class which offered the parallel execution of tests. However, this functionality was not publicly accessible until JUnit 4.7 which provided the possibility to set a custom scheduler for the parent runner.

```
public class ParallelScheduler implements RunnerScheduler {

    private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
        Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    @Override
    public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
        threadPool.submit(childStatement);
    }

    @Override
    public void finished() {
        try {
            threadPool.shutdown();
            threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException("Got interrupted", e);
        }
    }
}

public class ParallelRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public ParallelRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
        setScheduler(new ParallelScheduler());
    }
}
```

If you now annotate a test-class with `@RunWith(ParallelRunner.class)` each method will run within its own thread. Furthermore, there will be as many active threads (only) as CPU-cores are available at the executing machine.

If multiple classes should be executed in parallel you can define a customized suite like this:

```
public class ParallelSuite extends Suite {

    public ParallelSuite(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) 
      throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, builder);
        setScheduler(new ParallelScheduler());
    }
}
```

and then change `@RunWith(Suite.class)` with `@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)`

You can even leverage the functionality of f.e. the `WildcardPatternSuite` by extending directly from that suite instead of `Suite` as in the example before. This enables you furthermore to filter unit-tests f.e. by any `@Category` - a TestSuite which only executes `UnitTest` annotated categories in parallel could look like this:

```
public interface UnitTest {

}

@RunWith(ParallelSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses("**/*Test.class")
@IncludeCategories(UnitTest.class)
public class UnitTestSuite {

}
```

A simple test case could now look like this:

```
@Category(UnitTest.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `UnitTestSuite` will execute each class found in subdirecotries that ends with `Test` and has a `@Category(UnitTest.class)` specified in parallel - depending on the number of CPU cores available.

I'm not sure if it can get simpler than that :)

Comment: You don't have to rewrite this code. The author published a library named JUnit Toolbox: https://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/

Answer (score 6):

Apparently in his post *"Concurrent JUnit Tests With RunnerScheduler"* Mathieu Carbou has done implementation for concurrence that could helps!

http://dzone.com/articles/concurrent-junit-tests

OneJunit

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentJunitRunner.class)
@Concurrent(threads = 6)
public final class ATest {
 
    @Test public void test0() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test1() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test2() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test3() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test4() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test5() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test6() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test7() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test8() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }
    @Test public void test9() throws Throwable { printAndWait(); }

    void printAndWait() throws Throwable {
        int w = new Random().nextInt(1000);
        System.out.println(String.format("[%s] %s %s %s",Thread.currentThread().getName(), getClass().getName(), new Throwable       ().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), w));
        Thread.sleep(w);
    }
}
```

Multiple JUnits:

```
@RunWith(ConcurrentSuite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ATest.class, ATest2.class, ATest3.class})
public class MySuite {
}
```

Comment: This is pretty nice but doesn't seem to work with tests that include an @ BeforeClass and @ Before methods. It tries to run the @ BeforeClass methods for every thread instead of just once. For our setup, this means 5 threads dropping and rebuilding the DB at the same time :(

Comment: @Splaktar One way to solve this is to maintain a static reference to f.e. an `AtomicBoolean isInitialized` variable in the test class which is set after the before class method was executed once. Any additional invocations of the init-method will just return if this boolean variable is true. This prevents multiple threads from dropping already initialized data

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [HavaRunner](https://github.com/havarunner/havarunner). It is a JUnit runner that runs tests in parallel by default.

HavaRunner also has handy suites: you can declare a test to be a member of a suite by adding the annotation `@PartOf(YourIntegrationTestSuite.class)` onto the class. This approach differs from JUnit's, where you declare the suite memberships in the suite class.

In addition, HavaRunner suites may intialise heavy-weight objects such as an embedded web application container. HavaRunner then passes this heavy-weight object to the constructor of each suite member. This removes the need for the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations, which are problematic, because they promote global mutable state, which in turn makes parallelisation difficult.

Lastly, HavaRunner has scenarios – a way to run the same test against different data. Scenarios reduce the need to duplicate test code.

HavaRunner has been battle-tested in two mid-size Java projects.

Ps. I'm the author of HavaRunner, and I'd appreciate your feedback on it.