# how to turn non-parallel junit parameterized tests into parallel run

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, junit, concurrency

I write a parameterized junit test.

Is there any built-in way to make it run in parallel? any `@annoation` for example?

If not, and my only way is to write this manually -

how would you manage a thread pool in junit, java?

Comment: Dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing

Comment: but your link doesn't relate to parameterized test. right?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The library [JUnit Toolbox](https://github.com/MichaelTamm/junit-toolbox) provides a [ParallelParameterized](https://michaeltamm.github.io/junit-toolbox/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/ParallelParameterized.html) runner. Replace

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class YourTest {
```

with

```
@RunWith(ParallelParameterized.class)
public class YourTest {
```

Comment: and should i wrap with `sync` statement? only members that are called from within test methods? `@AfterClass` and `@BeforeClass` and the `ctor` are still called once and not parallel. right?

Comment: how can i check if it really runs in parallel?

Comment: First comment. `@AfterClass` and `@BeforeClass`: yes Constructor: no, it is called for each set of parameters

Comment: Second comment: why? What do you really want to test?