# Running junit parameterized tests (not classes) in parallel

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit4, junit5

I have a parameterized junit integration-test. It has 30 inputs (giving it 30 tests to run) and each takes 18 sec.

**I would like to run them in parallel.**

I'm running them from gradle and they are currently written in jUnit4, but i'm ready to switch to jUnit5 if that helps.

At the moment I can use gradles `maxParallelForks` but that only forks on classes.

Comment: In this response it use a thrid party library to do so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312191/how-to-turn-non-parallel-junit-parameterized-tests-into-parallel-run but maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have seen `JUnit Toolbox`. I was hoping for a native solution, especially with jUnit5 comming out pretty soon

Comment: As you mentioned, Gradle does not support parallel test execution at the method level. So if you want parallel execution of test methods within a single test class, you'll have to find an alternative solution that does not use Gradle's native testing support.

Comment: Regarding JUnit 5, there is currently no support for executing tests in parallel; however, there is an open issue to address this at a later date: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/60

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature is available since v 5.3

Create **src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties** with the following content:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
```

`junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default` will run test methods in the same class (including parameterized methods) in parallel.

There is also a `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default` to run tests from multiple classes in parallel. Check the picture in [jUnit 5 docs](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) to see the difference between 2 properties.

Comment: Warning: Parallel test execution is an experimental feature

Comment: This is not what the original question asked for. JUnit 5 can parallelize by class (which would not achieve any parallelism in this case) or by method (which would parallelize too much). The original question was asking for one thread per input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit 5 has built-in support for running tests in parallel. The official documentation is undoubtedly the best source to check it out:
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution