# Setting number of threads for JUnit execution

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, junit4

Poorly written unit tests are generally affected by the parallelism in JUnit execution. Can setting the number of threads for JUnit helps?

I read it somewhere, but I'm not sure. Can someone tell how can we set it? And where?

Comment: Can you please rephrase ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrent JUnit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing)

Comment: IMHO, by default JUnit does not execute tests in parallel, that's why someone else has written a parallel test runner.

Answer (score 3):

By defaul jUnit executes @Test methods in 4 threads. Howerver you can increase that number by putting:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism={numberOfThreads}
```

into:

```
src/main/resources/junit-platform.properties
```