# JUnit: is there a smart way to perform parallel testing?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

In my JUnit tests I want to perform parallel tests.

My first draft does not work:

```
@Test
public void parallelTestNotOk() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Runnable testcaseNotOk = () -> fail("This failure is not raised.");
    IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(i -> executor.submit(testcaseNotOk));
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Although each `testcaseNotOk` fails, this testcase succeeds. Why? Because `fail` is not called in the main thread, but in a parallel one?

My second draft works, because this testcase fails as expected:

```
@Test
public void parallelTestOk() throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Callable<AssertionError> testcaseOk = () -> {
        try {
            fail("This failure will be raised.");
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            return e;
        }
        return null;
    };
    List<Callable<AssertionError>> parallelTests = IntStream
            .range(0, 20).mapToObj(i -> testcaseOk)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<AssertionError> allThrownAssertionErrors = executor.invokeAll(parallelTests)
      .stream().map(future -> {
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).filter(assertionError -> assertionError != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    executor.shutdown();
    for (AssertionError e : allThrownAssertionErrors) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The following is done:

1. In `testcaseOk` the code to be tested is embedded into a try/catch block and every `AssertionError` rethrown.
2. `parallelTests` contains 20 times `testcaseOk`.
3. The `ExecutorService` performs all `parallelTests`.
4. If an `AssertionError` is thrown in `testcaseOk`, it will be collected into `allThrownAssertionErrors`.
5. If `allThrownAssertionErrors` contains any `AssertionError`, it will be thrown and the testcase `parallelTestOk()` will fail. Otherwise it will be ok.

My `parallelTestOk()` seems to be quite complicated. Is there an easier and smarter way (without using TestNG)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrent JUnit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is obsolete, as JUnit has included a parallel runner (easily usable with Maven and Gradle) since 4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you never check the value from the `Future` to see if the exception was thrown.

This will correctly fail the test:

```
@Test
public void parallelTestWillFail() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Runnable testcaseNotOk = () -> fail("This failure IS raised.");
    List<Future<?>> futures = IntStream.range(0, 20)
                                .mapToObj(i -> executor.submit(testcaseNotOk))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    executor.shutdown();
    for(Future<?> f : futures){
        f.get();
    }
}
```