# Any annotation to mark a class as a testclass?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am new to Junit4, I am wondering if there is some annotations to mark a class as a test class just like using

@Test to mark a method as a test method.

Comment: Why do you need an annotation that marks a class as test class? Do you want to dynamically load and execute these via test suites similar to a [scenario depicted in this thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing/26234336#26234336)

Comment: As of JUnit 5 there are arcane rules that I have not seen documented any place.  First, the test class must be named XxxTest or some name ending with "Test". If you don't do this JUnit will not run the tests even if you annotate the methods with @Test.   There should be a way to mark a class named without Test on the end as a test class, but I have not found it yet either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Category` annotation at class level, like:

```
@Category({PerformanceTests.class, RegressionTests.class})
public class ClassB {

    @Test
    public void test_b_1() {
        assertThat(1 == 1, is(true));
    }

}
```

I quoted this example from https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-categories-test/

Also if you run Spring tests, Mockito test with JUnit, then you have to use `@RunWith` annotation at class level.

For example in Spring boot test I use this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class ControllerTest {
```

In Mockito (without spring test) test I used:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotation `@TestOnly`, but it does come with a warning, as seen below.

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly;
```

**WARNING**

```
/**
 * A member or type annotated with TestOnly claims that it should be used from testing code only.
 * <p>
 * Apart from documentation purposes this annotation is intended to be used by static analysis tools
 * to validate against element contract violations.
 * <p>
 * This annotation means that the annotated element exposes internal data and breaks encapsulation 
 * of the containing class; the annotation won't prevent its use from production code, developers 
 * won't even see warnings if their IDE doesn't support the annotation. It's better to provide 
 * proper API which can be used in production as well as in tests.
 */
```

**WORKAROUND**

If there are bodies of code or classes that I use specifically for testing and need to remove them at release I add a custom `TODO` using Android Studio (Not sure if other IDEs have the same functionality), follow the screenshot below and in the TODO tab at the bottom, you will see a filter for each custom `TODO` on the left. This is by no means the best way to do it, but I find it the fastest manual way to remove code on release.

[image: Custom TODO in Android Studio]

[image: TODO Filter]

P.S I know the patterns are all sorts of messed up in this screenshot.