# Class-level test annotation in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

TestNG has a nice feature whereby the `@Test` annotation is added to the test *class* (instead of the test *method*). When the class is annotated, all public void-returning methods on the class are treated as test methods, as per the [documentation](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#class-level).

```
@Test
public class Test1 {
  public void test1() {
  }
  public void test2() {
  }
}
```

Does JUnit 5 support a similar concept?
If not, is there an extension that would allow Junit 5 to be extended?

(I can't find any discussion of class-level annotations wrt JUnit 5, maybe I've missed it. Having to annotate each method is error-prone, with a high chance of forgetting to annotate a method, and thus having the tests not run, creating a false sense of confidence.)

Update: Now raised as an [issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1761).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45241313/any-annotation-to-mark-a-class-as-a-testclass

Comment: @孙兴斌:  Categories are worlds divorced from what the OP is referring to.

Comment: As an aside:  having written Java tests for a long time now, you quickly remember to annotate your methods.  Leaning on your tooling can also help you remember to annotate those methods too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't available in JUnit 5.

For a time in JUnit 3, you could extend the `TestCase` class and then all of your methods which were prefixed with `test*` would be run automatically, but not only was that more subject to breakage, it's actually actively deprecated and modern frameworks won't run with those older-style tests.