# How to run multithreaded/stress tests with junit5?

Tags: testng, junit5

I'm using TestNG support for multithreaded and stress tests and I would like to use JUnit5 instead of TestNG but I could not find how to do it.

JUnit4 doesn't support multithreaded tests: [Concurrent JUnit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970907/concurrent-junit-testing)

With TestNG multithreaded tests are very simple:

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 3, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 10000)
public void testServer() {
  ...
}
```

See: 
https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/annotations/Test.java#L57

How can I run multithreaded tests with JUnit5?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but JUnit is not designed to perform stress test. You can do the same thing with JUnit 4 or 5 but you will have to write code to start threads yourself.

Comment: Great question. I don't think Junit5 community has it out of the box. (too bad!)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using `JUnit5 + Gradle`, just add

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}
```

in the `build.gradle` and Gradle automatically run all test classes in parallel depending on available processors or other option you set (for more info please see https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#parallel_test_execution)

Best,
Oleg

Comment: I want to run the same test with multiple threads to test multithreaded code or to do stress tests. Your answer is for running different tests in parallel.